# How to access proxy_url\auth in urllib3.ProxyManager

Tags: python, urllib3

I'm working right now on project (not mine to clarify) which scraps some sites using urllib3 to make requests and some of them are under CF protection. I found some cfscrape (etc etc list of similar names) library that is a wrapper of requests.Session which may help with circumventing antibot measures of CF but there is a catch, I need proxies which are fetched by API and put into ProxyManager objects. In devenv I have no access to those proxies because of policy. Is there an easy way to get proxy url and auth from ProxyManager or do I need to add some square wheels (aka save them somewhere else as second copy) to integrate that library into project with little work as possible without degrading performance by that much? Don't really want to rewrite urllib3 usage to requests.Session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question - ProxyManager does have easy access tho it's kinda strange that I couldn't find anything in the docs (maybe I overlooked it)